# what does $\cdot^\rho$ mean in the Harish-Chandra function?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Wikipedia defines the Harish Chandra function on a semisimple Lie group to be $$g\mapsto \int_Ka(kg)^\rho dk$$ where $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup, $a(g)$ is the $A$ factor in the Iwasawa decomposition of $g$ and $\rho$ is the Weyl vector (half the sum of the positive roots).  What does it mean to put that vector in the superscript?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra%27s_%CE%9E_function

Comment: Good question! and, I have no idea. In Lie theory, the usual narrative is that the connection between everything is clear when you set your origin at $-\rho$. I can't speculate what that would mean in this context.