# What is the Harish Chandra function?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm struggling to find a definition of the Harish Chandra function (usually denoted $\Xi$) online. Could you tell me what it is? There is a definition on wikipedia that I asked about in this post, but I don't understand the notation used there.

[what does $\cdot^\rho$ mean in the Harish-Chandra function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458390/what-does-cdot-rho-mean-in-the-harish-chandra-function)

Comment: Why did you post the same question again?

Comment: @ClementC. I saw the first question as a question about the notation used in a particular definition. This question is asking for any definition.